# xcode duplicates files in project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm at a complete loss as to what I did to cause this:
For the second time since I started using XCode about a month ago (my first time seriously using it after taking one class several years ago) I try to run my project and the next thing I know I have errors because I have duplicate references. I looked at the project and it appeared that most of the files in my project had duplicated themselves, however I discovered that they are not duplicate files just duplicate references. This happened to me today when I tried to build on an actual iphone for the first time but it also happened to me a few weeks ago while using the simulator. Neither time do I recall doing anything unusual. I have built and tested the project probably 100+ times and normally all goes ok. I was able to fix it the first time but I think I have made it worse this time and am probably going to add the files back into a new project. My co-worker also mentioned this happening to him (he has about as much experience with xcode as I do). He told me he ended up with files nested in folders (groups?) nested in other folders about 20 deep.

My question is this: Does anyone know what I may have done to cause this. I would really like to avoid this problem in the future since it is proving to be quite a headache. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

E.T.A. xcode version 4.6.2 (possibly an earlier version the first time it happened)

Comment: The most likely way for this to happen is if you're "adding an existing file" and you accidentally double click while navigating through the directory structure to find the file.  Bingo!  You've added everything in the directory you double-clicked.  Can also happen with some accidental drag-and-drop scenarios while working on the file list.

Comment: You didn't do anything. It's a bug. Sometimes you just have to clean up the references. Validating your archive checks for these duplicate references, so it's easy to catch these before you distribute the app.

Comment: This bug has happened to me to. Did you recently restore a snapshot? I think that is what caused it for me.

Comment: @HotLicks I wasn't adding an existing file however I think that is what I was doing the first time this happened. It is possible it was due to drag and drop dropping. I don't remember exactly what I was doing right before because someone came up and asked me to build the program on an iphone which snapped me out of my train of thought. I noticed it when I switched from the simulator to the phone and tried to run it. However it may have been whatever I did right before that. I was trying to do something with the storyboard but I don't remember my exact steps. Thank you for the insight though.

Comment: One thing to do is, as soon as you realize you've mucked it up, do Ctrl-Z to "undo".  This only works, of course, if you've made no other changes since.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

1. Highlight all the duplicate files
2. Right click on one of the files and press "Delete"
3. When prompted for which delete option, click "Remove Reference"

Comment: If they're duplicates you want to DELETE the reference, not just remove it. Clicking "Remove Reference" will keep the files in the folder and make it messier for later.

Comment: I'm accepting @AbdouSarr's answer because I'm pretty sure that is what I did to fix my project the first time around, although this time I am rebuilding it because the project file is deleted. I think I did that myself while trying to 'fix' everything. I would still like to know how to avoid running into this in the future however.

Comment: @Collin - You want to delete the files if indeed there are duplicate files.  But when I've seen this is has pretty much always been that there are just duplicate references and only one physical file, so "remove reference" is the right way to do it.

Comment: (If you're unsure as to whether there are multiple physical copies open a Finder window, navigate to your project (double-click on the project directory to make it the "current directory" for Finder), then type the file name in the search field.)

Comment: @HotLicks - thanks. I will make sure I check if there are duplicate references or duplicate files. Thats where I went wrong this time. I deleted some of non-duplicates instead of removing references.

Answer (score 2):

Also you asked for "any advice".
If you aren't already using git source control in your Xcode projects, start now.
You can spot many mistakes like this earlier and fix them more easily using git.

When you add files as a copy, the Xcode project navigator shows added files with an A and modified files with an M.

[image: Modified and Added files]

If the file is inside a closed group folder, the folder shows an A.

[image: Added file copy inside closed group folder]

If you add a reference without a copy the project navigator won't show an A but MyApp.xcodeproj will show M.

In Xcode you can discard a change before committing it.
In the case below, you would discard changes to all added or modified files.

[image: discard changes]

Typically you review and commit changes frequently.
Using a gui tool such as SourceTree, you have a good chance of spotting an accidental change before you commit. For example, you can see changes to the project file.

[image: SourceTree, a gui for git]

If you accidentally commit an unintended change, you can go back later and reverse a commit.
By committing frequently, you have more control over which changes you undo and which ones you keep.

References:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

http://git-scm.com/doc (scroll down to see videos)

http://www.sourcetreeapp.com

http://gitimmersion.com

Comment: Thank-you very much for your advice. I was already using git but to be honest I wasn't using it as frequently or as well as I should have been. I have been reading and learning much more about git now and I am finding it very useful. Also regarding the 'M' and 'A' showing in the file inspector. I did not know that and that is very useful information.Thankyou so much. I have been reading a ton of books and websites about objective-c and xcode and that is the first I've seen of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 20 deep nesting of my main folder of images. If its not a bug its very strange behaviour. I just backed it all up !! Then I opened the folder in finder, found the point at which it was starting to nest and deleted it.

I did a rebuild, but I don't think Xcode even noticed. It made no difference to the size of my app so Xcode was not putting unnecessary files in the binary.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I imported a file. Suddenly I had two nested directories containing what looked like copies of all my files. The compiler complained about duplicate classes.

I found a solution, but it's a ball-ache and a time sink.

1: Click on your project in the navigator to open up the project settings in the main view.

2: Open the 'Compile Sources' accordion entry.
(This allows you to see which files are being used in the compilation process.)

3: Find any duplicates in here and delete them.
(At this stage your project should compile again.)

4: In your navigator view, slow-double-click one of the files that's duplicated there. This should allow you to rename it. Change the name (not the extension) slightly.

5: You should notice that the copy becomes red. Select it and hit delete.
(This avoids the delete operation removing the file from the 'Compile Sources')

6: Rename the original file back to its original name again.

7: Repeat from 4 until done, or until bored.

8: Explain to your boss why a simple copy change took half a day.

This process can be optimised up by first renaming all duplicated files, then deleting the duplicates all at once. However this means that you can't test for successful compilation between steps, which allows you to narrow the culprit down to a single file. And takes even more time.

If compilation fails, ensure all the files you need are still in the 'Compile Sources' section, as this process can cause them to be lost from there. The compiler will normally give some reasonable errors about missing classes and variables, but a missing AppDelegate will produce a more confusing error.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, using a SCM tool like Git will allow you to return to a known good state. It has saved my sorry ass on many occasion.